# Getting a QSqlRecord from QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt4

I have a `QSqlTableModel` which I want to add a `QSqlRecord` to it. I'm supposing `QSqlTableModel::record()` should return a `QSqlRecord` containing fields but no data. [Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html#record) says:

> `QSqlRecord QSqlQueryModel::record () const`
>
> This is an overloaded function. Returns an empty record containing
>   information about the fields of the current query. If the model is not
>   initialized, an empty record will be returned.

The problem is that `record` returns and empty record with no field:

```
// Prepare DB, open, initialize model, even ::select() on the model 
this->record = this->model->record(); // <== returns an empty record
qDebug() << record; // Prints: QSqlRecord( 0 ) 
qDebug() << record.count(); // Prints: 0
// So these operation will do nothing:
record.setValue("name","some foo");
...
```

Comment: Are you talking about QSqlTableModel or QSqlQueryModel? That part of documentation is about QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: @Nejat `QSqlTableModel` inherits `QSqlQueryModel`. `this->model` is a `QSqlTableModel`

Comment: Try to see record.fieldName(int index) to see if it contains field names.